# How can I access the mounted web camera of NVIDIA JETSON AGX XAVIER using python?

Tags: python, jetson-xavier

I have an **NVIDIA JETSON AGX XAVIER**. I have mounted a camera to that. I need to access this camera through my laptop using python and capture some video and save them back to my laptop again. I have searched for anything that helpful for solving this problem. But I haven't found one. Even I did not find any question related to my problem on this website itself.

If anyone has done this before or anyone has an idea where to refer, please help me to get this work done.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already boot into the Xavier using your laptop?

If you are using python and video capturing then, [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) is the way to go.


You can check out [JetsonHacks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08OAN9m0TjM) on YouTube for the basics.


Here's the [repo](https://github.com/jetsonhacks/buildOpenCVXavier) which isn't linked on the video.

Comment: Actually I need to find a method to access every mounted camera to the Jetson Xavier using my laptop. The resource you have provided, It allows to access the camera by logging to the Jetson it self